# Solving a functional equation [methodology]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, functional-equations

I have an issue regarding the correct methodology to solve a **functional equation**.

The aim is to find all the **differentiable** functions defined as $f:\,]0,+\infty[ \rightarrow R$ such as :
$$
(E) :f'(x)f \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{1}{x}
$$

**Personnal attempt :**

Supposing $f$ is a solution, we can assume that $f$ is differentiable therefore continuous. We can then differentiate $(E)$ and we get :
$$
(E)' : f''(x)f \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)- \frac{1}{x^2}f'(x)f' \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = -\frac{1}{x^2}
$$

If we pose $x = \frac{1}{x}$ we can obtain (supposing that $f' \ne 0$) :

$$
\frac{1}{x}\frac{f''}{f'} - \frac{1}{x} \frac{f'}{f} = -\frac{1}{x^2}
$$

Therefore, we can integrate the equation, then apply an exponential and we end up with a 1-st order differential equation.

**Book's solution :**

They start by substituting $x = \frac{1}{x}$ then, they get the equation :

$$
f' \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)f(x) = x
$$

After that, they suppose :

$$
g(x) = f \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)f(x)
$$

By differentiating, we get $g'(x) = 0$ therefore : $g(x) =f \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)f(x)= C$ which means we can write:

$$
f'(x) = \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{f \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)} = \frac{\frac{1}{x} f(x)}{f \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)f(x)} = \frac{1}{xCf(x)}
$$

which **also** leads to a 1-st order differential equation but this time : it's different than the one that I personally obtain.

**Question**

My method seems to be false but I don't understand why : is there a convenient methodology (steps-by-step) for solving functional equations that leads to avoid these kind of misunderstanding ?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Best regards.

Comment: With your extra derivative you invite a spurious integration constant. As far as I can see your method is correct, leading to $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{C}{x}$ and then $f(x)=Dx^C$, but there is a dependence between the integration constants.

Comment: Thanks @LutzLehmann for your input. It annoys me that my method is not as elegant as the one provided in the solution. It depends on the way that I perform the integration. This is why I am surprised to read the solution of my book : I was wondering if there is a typical procedure to follow for solving such equations.